# How to install GestureRecognizer component in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have built an application that uses the GestureRecognizer (System.Windows.Ink.GestureRecognizer).  The problem is that when testing it on some machines, IsRecognizerAvailable returns false.  These systems are running .NET 3.5 and 4, so updates shouldn't be the problem.  Can anyone tell me how to specifically install the GestureRecognizer component on systems where it is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the OS on the machines where you don't get Recognizer. What I know is that Windows Ink support is limited on Windows XP/2K (its available on XP Tablet edition) but should be present in vistas onwards. Quoting from the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701189(v=vs.85).aspx - essentially indicates that gestures will not be available in windows XP.

> Reduced Feature Set
>
> Ink-enabled applications treat mouse
>   events as pen movements to simulate
>   working with a tablet pen. Users can
>   add ink, erase ink, and save ink
>   documents. However, recognition and
>   gestures are not available for users
>   other than those running Windows XP
>   Tablet PC Edition.